# pass data from javascript to php via ajax, select a myslq table dynamically and retrieve the data of the query in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i am stuck with ajax and php, i would like to pass information to a php file that communicate with mysql and retrieve data in a variables. 
For the moment i managed to pass data via javascript to php, i can't to do the opposite.

Here is the code 
HTML CODE

```
<form action="">
           <select name="misura" onchange="show(this.value)">
           <option value="">scegli la misura</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           -->
           <option value="husqvarna_272xp_catena_nuova_operatore_1">husqvarna_272xp_catena_nuova_operatore_1</option>
           <option value="husqvarna_550xp_catena_usata_operatore_2">husqvarna_550xp_catena_usata_operatore_2</option>
           <option value="husqvarna_550xp_catena_usata_operatore_1">husqvarna_550xp_catena_usata_operatore_1</option>
           <option value="husqvarna_550xp_catena_nuova_operatore_2">husqvarna_550xp_catena_nuova_operatore_2</option>
           <option value="husqvarna_550xp_catena_nuova_operatore_1">husqvarna_550xp_catena_nuova_operatore_1</option>
        </select>
        </form>
       </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT/AJAX

```
function show(str){
    var xhttp; 
    if(str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML ="";
        return;
    }
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
       }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","database_web.php?q="+str, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

PHP CODE IN THE FILE DATABASE.PHP

```
<?php

$q = intval($_GET['q']);


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASS","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 
$dati="SELECT * FROM ".$_GET['q']."";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$dati);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Frequenza</th>
<th>dati_X</th>
<th>dati_Y</th>
<th>dati_z</th>
</tr>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . round($row[0],2) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . round($row[1],2) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . round($row[2],2) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . round($row[3],2) . "</td>";


    $prova = $row;
    $xData[] =  $row[0];
    }
mysqli_close($con);
```

Convert to json in the file database.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// pass PHP variable declared above to JavaScript variable


  // operatore 1 antivibrante
  // misura 1 exp
 var  assex = 
  <?php echo json_encode($xData) ;?>;
  console.log(assex);
</script>
```

In the console.log i can't view nothing and i can't understand why. 
My objective are to retrieve data from sql interrogation and create a graph dynamically with the data.

I made a page for testing in this address

http://www.rdgdesign.it/elaboration/ajax_web.php

Thanks for all !

Comment: To be honest, I don't get your problem. When I visit your page and select an option a table with some values is shown.

Comment: First you don't need to echo your table, you need to `echo (json_encode($xData))` before mysqli_close($con). That way you will get json when you do console.log. If you want array in console.log then in your database.php, put print_r($xData) before mysqli_close();

Comment: It works for me. Use your developer tools in your browser to put a breakpoint on the line `document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;` and look at `this.responseText`. Your php program sends a lot of stuff to the browser other than your table.

Comment: I tried to put json_encode before mysqli_close but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How i can see with the breakpoint Jones? Thanks